# ANTLR4 predicate failure ignores following alternative?

Tags: parsing, antlr, text-parsing, antlr4

I'm having trouble with semantic predicates in ANTLR 4. My grammar is syntactically ambiguous, and needs to look ahead one token to resolve the ambiguity.

As an example, I want to parse "Jan 19, 2012 until 9 pm" as the date "Jan 19, 2012" leaving parser's next token at "until". And I want to parse "Jan 19, 7 until 9 pm" as the date "Jan. 19" with parser's next token at "7".

So I need to look at the 3rd token and either take it or leave it.

My grammar fragment is:

```
date
    :    month d=INTEGER  { isYear(getCurrentToken().getText())}?  y=INTEGER
                                    {//handle date, use $y for year}
    |    month d=INTEGER            {//handle date, use 2013 for year}
    ;
```

When the parser runs on either sample input, I get this message:

```
line 1:9 rule date failed predicate: { isYear(getCurrentToken().getText())}?
```

It never gets to the 2nd rule alternative, because (I'm guessing) it's already read one extra token.

Can someone show me how to accomplish this?

Comment: One solution would be to use two parsers, the first is as above without the predicate. It prints out "$DATE(2012-1-19) until 9 pm" for first input, and "$DATE(2013-1-19), 7 until 9 pm" for the 2nd input. But if other ambiguities like this arise, this becomes an n-parser solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In parser rules, ANTLR 4 only uses predicates on the left edge when *making* a decision. Inline predicates like the one you showed above are only *validated*.

The following modification will cause ANTLR to evaluate the predicate while it makes the decision, but obviously you'll need to modify it to use the correct lookahead token instead of calling `getCurrentToken()`.

```
date
  : {isYear(getCurrentToken().getText())}? month d=INTEGER y=INTEGER
                                {//handle date, use $y for year}
  | month d=INTEGER             {//handle date, use 2013 for year}
  ;
```

PS: If `month` is always exactly one token long, then `_input.LT(3)` should provide the token you want.

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant LT(3), LA(3) gives me a syntax error. This solves my issue.